# Nested when in Pyspark

Tags: sql, pandas, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I need to apply lots of when conditions which take input from a list by indexes. I wanted to ask if there's a way to write the code efficiently which produces the same results without affecting the runtime efficiency.

Below is the code I am using

```
df=df.withColumn('date_match_label', F.when(F.col(date_cols[0])==F.col(date_cols[3]), f"{date_cols[0]} matches with {date_cols[3]}")
                                  .when(F.col(date_cols[0])==F.col(date_cols[3]), f"{date_cols[1]} matches with {date_cols[3]}")
                                  .when(F.col(date_cols[0])==F.col(date_cols[3]), f"{date_cols[1]} matches with {date_cols[3]}")
                                  .when(F.col(date_cols[1])==F.col(date_cols[4]), f"{date_cols[1]} matches with {date_cols[4]}")
                                  .when(F.col(date_cols[1])==F.col(date_cols[4]), f"{date_cols[1]} matches with {date_cols[4]}")
                                  .when(F.col(date_cols[1])==F.col(date_cols[4]), f"{date_cols[1]} matches with {date_cols[4]}")
                                  .when(F.col(date_cols[2])==F.col(date_cols[5]), f"{date_cols[1]} matches with {date_cols[5]}")
                                  .when(F.col(date_cols[2])==F.col(date_cols[5]), f"{date_cols[1]} matches with {date_cols[5]}")
                                  .when(F.col(date_cols[2])==F.col(date_cols[5]), f"{date_cols[1]} matches with {date_cols[5]}")
                                  .otherwise('No Match'))
```

Here date_cols contains six column names. I need to check the first three columns with the last three columns and return the comment if there's a match.

The problem with current approach is as the size of the list increases, I'll have to add more and more lines which makes my code prone to errors and looks ugly. I was wondering if there's a way to that where I only need to specify the list indices which need to be compared against the other list elements.

Answer (score 0):

- Considering you want to compare the 1st half of the list (with column names) to second half of the list, you can dynamically build the code expression so that there wouldn't be any need to write more error prone code each time the list expands.
- You can build the code dynamically with the help of indices in the following way:

```
from itertools import product
from pyspark.sql.functions import when,col

n=len(cols)
req=list(range(0,n))

res = list(product(req[:n//2], req[n//2:]))

start = '''df.withColumn('date_match_label','''

whens =[]
for i,j in res:
    whens.append(f'''when(col(cols[{i}])==col(cols[{j}]), f"cols[{i}] matches with cols[{j}]")''')
    
final_exp = start + '.'.join(whens) + '''.otherwise('No Match'))'''
```

- This will generate the final expession as shown below considering there are 4 columns (comparing 1st half with 2nd half):

[image]

- The above is a string expression. So, to execute it you can use `eval` function and get results as shown below:

```
df = eval(final_exp)
df.show(truncate=False)
```

[image]